# Is a distributed queue suitable for building a scalable case assignment system?

Tags: architecture, distributed-system

This is the basic functionality I’m targeting.

1. A new user registers with their details and uploads some documents. This creates a new case.
2. Auditors login every morning and pick a pending case from the backlog.
3. If all documents look good, auditors approve, otherwise reject the case.

My take

1. `/register` POST method endpoint that runs a which captures the details from the user in a sharded MySQL database, and any files that they submitted in a BLOB storage (references updated in  MySQL).
2. Successful registration emits an event with the user ID to a distributed queue, for the time being I’m considering Amazon SQS but I want to find out if there are any open source alternatives that can prevent me from a vendor lock in.
3. `/audit` POST method endpoint which the auditor will call to fetch one entry from the queue (SQS) and also update the status of this case, so other auditors don’t end up getting the same case. If they were able to obtain a lock for this case, good otherwise try again with the next item from the queue.
4. `/register` and `/audit` would be separate services, so they can be scaled up and down independently.

I’m having second thoughts about introducing a queue in the first place. Am I better off just querying the database? Something like `SELECT Id FROM USER WHERE status = ‘Pending’ FOR UPDATE`

How would you build a system that can handle scale according to /registration usage and /auditor usage? How would you build a system that can handle dynamically scale according to registration load and auditor load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’m having second thoughts about introducing a queue in the first place. Am I better off just querying the database? Something like SELECT Id FROM USER WHERE status = ‘Pending’ FOR UPDATE

Queues are usually introduced in automatic pipelines to desynchronize and decouple the single processing steps, but this does not seem to be your case.  Also, at this level, a queue per se is very similar to a plain table, it mainly adds a notification system on top of it (locking you already get in SQL), so, if you can send an email or similar from your program, that on top of some dedicated tables should be all you need.

So, I think you do are fine with a table (or rather, group of related tables) representing the *registration data and approval state* (the approval state definition itself coming from a state-transition diagram or similar that specifies the *approval life-cycle*).

On the other hand, I would advice against just doing it all within the main USER table: certainly so if you want scalability, but I think this would be advisable in any case for clarity and manageability of such an implementation.

> How would you build a system that can handle dynamically scale according to registration load and auditor load?

Saying "dynamically scale" is a bit improper, either the system is designed to scale, or it isn't: in other words, we may "dynamically scale" on e.g. server resources, not on application logic and code.  That said, I would go with dedicated tables as explained above, which does scale.

Comment: You're right. Most of queues are meant for decoupling automatic pipelines from the request thread. The solution I proposed with SQS is definitely an odd choice. 


Assuming you agree with the other approach of using SELECT FOR UPDATE that I've proposed above,  I'm wondering how to handle two simultaneous /audit requests that get redirected to the same MySQL shard. One of the requests wouldn't be able to acquire the lock because they both will evaluate to the same case record, and thus fail. Do I just retry for such an observed failure?

Comment: I do agree with that approach *as long as* by SELECT FOR UPDATE you mean *record-level* locking... but I am not sure how representative that piece of code is: if you put that in a transaction and the actual UPDATE in a subsequent one, that would not work as expected.

Comment: The problem of *concurrency* is really its own question and not a simple one (there is a hierarchy of possible solutions, actual solutions depending on concrete requirements), so just a couple hints: 1) here the problem seems limited to "concurrent approval by admin", so, unless explicitly needed, a simple solution without automatic retries may be enough;  2) the simplest and most common solution indeed does not even lock, just raises *at the UPDATE* with an "ERROR: Already modified", and only requires checking a modification date or similar of the submitted record vs the one in the db...

Comment: In fact, a very common solution is to just overwrite silently, but I would advice against that one... :)

Comment: In most likelihood the number of concurrent auditor requests wouldn’t be so overwhelming that they are contending for the same record, but I’m looking for options to break that tie if ends up happening down the line. 

I’m exploring the option to efficiently return a random record matching a criteria. I see a lot of posts on Stackoverflow about it, but the opinions are mixed about it’s efficiency.

Comment: Honestly, I see a lot of mispatterns and solving the wrong if even existent problem, especially when it comes to data patterns.  Here it's not even clear to me what you are after, just let me point out that the "concurrency problem" is what I have started to explain above, and it's *not* the problem of two *single* commands arriving at the server at exactly the same time...

Comment: How are the two things different? 

Each `/audit` call would return a case record, and simultaneously modify the assignedTo field to the admin’s ID who called the request.

Won’t two concurrent case assignment requests translate to running the same SQL query on the database to fetch one case record? In which case, either one of the two query executions would fail. I want to minimise these kind of failures from happening from the first place, by bringing a sort of randomness in case assignment. 

@Julio I hope that clarifies what I’m after and what I mean when I say concurrency problem.

Comment: What "simultaneous"??  You are simply being way too imprecise.  Two SELECT or UPDATE commands issued at exactly the same moment (if that is even possible), one will simply *queue* on the another, as it is for e.g. `lock` in C#, and you have to do *nothing* there (except knowing how it works and how it can be fine tuned).  The problem and the only problem here is *concurrency of **transactions***...   And that is 1) another question than "should I use a queue here", and 2) a question I cannot just answer in a bunch of comments, which is *inappropriate* for SO anyway!

Comment: Yeah you’re right.
 I was looking at SELECT FOR UPDATE  wrong. It’s impossible for two concurrent requests to even read the same record because of the exclusive lock mechanism of SELECT FOR UPDATE (granted the right isolation mode and a transaction context). So if there is a case backlog, both these requests will fetch two different case records.